# Why does the Streaming-Operator in SystemVerilog reverse the byte order?

Tags: system-verilog

I simulated the following example:

```
shortint j;
byte unsigned data_bytes[];

j = 16'b1111_0000_1001_0000;
data_bytes = { >>{j}};
`uvm_info(get_type_name(), $sformatf("j data_bytes: %b_%b", data_bytes[1], data_bytes[0]), UVM_LOW)
```

Result:

```
UVM_INFO Initiator.sv(84) @ 0: uvm_test_top.sv_initiator [Initiator] j data_bytes: 10010000_11110000
```

However, this seems strange to me, since the byte-order is reversed, as I expect the LSB to be at index 0 of data_byte[0] and the MSB at index 7 of data_byte[1]. Why does this happen? According to documentation (Cadence Help) this should not be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As defined in section *6.24.3 Bit-stream casting* of the IEEE 1800-2017 LRM, the `[0]` element of an unpacked dynamic array is considered the left index, and streaming `>>` goes from *left to right* indexes. To get the results you want, write

```
data_bytes = { << byte {j}};
```

This reverses the stream, but keeps the individual bytes in right to left order.